# How to destroy an own ceiling?

Tags: rust

We created a three floor house in the middle of the mountain and we would like now to expand it by creating additional floors. But it seems that C4 does not work on ceilings, so we are blocked at the moment. Is there any other option?

[image: Our house]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, destroying your own ceilings can't be done at the moment. Sorry!

Their road map had stated that they were looking into permission changes and allowing the destruction of the things you build in future updates. At the moment, however, Rust's Reddit forum states ceilings will only go away by "decay". The inability to destroy the ceilings is confirmed on the Rust wiki.

- [Reddit Post](http://www.reddit.com/r/playrust/comments/1vam6q/official_destructible_items_list/)
- [Rust Wiki](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Wood_Ceiling)

With the decay feature, you'll essentially have to wait for your base to degrade over time. Each layer, from the top down, will essentially "go away" after around 4 days each. You will likely have to wait for your ceilings to disappear and then continue building your base from there. If you add onto that layer of your structure, however, it'll reset the timer and you'll have to wait longer for it to degrade. Not sure if using doors will reset the timer as well.

Comment: Can you please verify the answer?

Comment: Edited with sources.

Comment: This answer is true, you could however destroy a wall, build another foundation witha  staircase there and build on the other floor agian.